# PostGIS compilation issue with PostgreSQL 14

Tags: postgis, compile

I am trying to compile PostGIS 3.1.1 from source under the newly released PostgreSQL 14 beta1. I downloaded the latest PostGIS source and then compiled it under Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as follows:

```
tar xf postgis-3.1.1.tar.gz
cd postgis-3.1.1
./configure
make
```

And it generates the following errors:

```
...
gcc -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror=vla -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wcast-function-type -Wformat-security -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -Wno-format-truncation -Wno-stringop-truncation -g -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fPIC -I../liblwgeom -std=gnu99 -g -O2 -fno-math-errno -fno-signed-zeros -I../libpgcommon -I../deps/wagyu -I../deps/uthash/include  -I/opt/geos/include   -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I/opt/sfcgal/include -I/usr/include/json-c  -DNDEBUG   -fPIC -DPIC -I. -I./ -I/usr/include/postgresql/14/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal  -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2   -c -o gserialized_supportfn.o gserialized_supportfn.c
gserialized_supportfn.c: In function ‘postgis_index_supportfn’:
gserialized_supportfn.c:420:40: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  420 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index((Node*)expandexpr, req->index))
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                        |
      |                                        Node *
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:55: note: expected ‘PlannerInfo *’ but argument is of type ‘Node *’
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
gserialized_supportfn.c:420:62: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  420 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index((Node*)expandexpr, req->index))
      |                                                           ~~~^~~~~~~
      |                                                              |
      |                                                              struct IndexOptInfo *
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:67: note: expected ‘Node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct IndexOptInfo *’
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |                                                             ~~~~~~^~~~
gserialized_supportfn.c:420:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’
  420 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index((Node*)expandexpr, req->index))
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:13: note: declared here
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gserialized_supportfn.c:443:40: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  443 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index(rightarg, req->index))
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~
      |                                        |
      |                                        Node *
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:55: note: expected ‘PlannerInfo *’ but argument is of type ‘Node *’
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |                                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~
gserialized_supportfn.c:443:53: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  443 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index(rightarg, req->index))
      |                                                  ~~~^~~~~~~
      |                                                     |
      |                                                     struct IndexOptInfo *
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:67: note: expected ‘Node *’ but argument is of type ‘struct IndexOptInfo *’
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |                                                             ~~~~~~^~~~
gserialized_supportfn.c:443:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘is_pseudo_constant_for_index’
  443 |      if (!is_pseudo_constant_for_index(rightarg, req->index))
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from gserialized_supportfn.c:38:
/usr/include/postgresql/14/server/optimizer/optimizer.h:100:13: note: declared here
  100 | extern bool is_pseudo_constant_for_index(PlannerInfo *root, Node *expr,
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [<builtin>: gserialized_supportfn.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '.../postgis-3.1.1/postgis'
make: *** [GNUmakefile:22: all] Error 1
```

PostgreSQL 14 is installed via `apt` from the official repo at http://apt.postgresql.org, and both `postgresql-14` `postgresql-server-dev-14` are installed.

Does anyone know of a fix for this issue with the new PostgreSQL 14?

Comment: You should ask on the postgis mailing list https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/postgis-users/ or open an issue at https://github.com/postgis/postgis/issues At the moment, there is no build done for PostgreSQL 14.0 due to beta (see no version 14.0 in Travis CI in PostGIS official repo https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/master/.travis.yml) Except PostGIS core devs, will be difficult to get help

Comment: @ThomasG77, I understand that. I am just hoping to add a data point here for the PostGIS developers since GIS.SE is mentioned on the PostGIS support page https://postgis.net/support/ and they might notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PostGIS 3.1.2 is now released. And it compiles with PostgreSQL 14 in the same environment.

According to the [NEWS](https://git.osgeo.org/gitea/postgis/postgis/raw/tag/3.1.2/NEWS)

> - #4845, Add Pg14 build support (Paul Ramsey)